# How can I stretch text to horizontally fit dynamically generated div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My code parses an external page and creates a div to display that page's data. I found a script here on stack overflow that is supposed to stretch a text to a div width, this one http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/DPRr9/, but I'm not being able to make it work with my script, it looks like it is not working because my code's div is generated dynamically, so the jQuery code actually isn't seeing any div to integrate to.

```
<?php
    $xml = new DOMDocument();
    @$xml->loadHTMLFile('http://v2.afilio.com.br/aff/aff_boutique_show_ads.php?boutiqueid=37930-895777&currencypos=0&display_img=1&diplay_name=1&diplay_price=1&thumbsize=80%&truncate_desc=1&numrows=1&numcols=9&colorname=000000&colorprice=E30000&bkcolor=FFFFFF&bordercolor=FFFFFF&self_target=0&');

    $products = array();

    //Loop through each <td> tag in the dom and extract inner html    
    foreach($xml->getElementsByTagName('td') as $p) {
        $children  = $p->childNodes;
        $phtml = '';
        foreach ($children as $child)
        {
            $phtml.= $p->ownerDocument->saveHTML($child);
        }

        echo '<div id="mainproductafilioright"><div class="product">' . $phtml . '</div></div>';
    }
?>
```

The line that generates the div is:

```
echo '<div id="mainproductafilioright"><div class="product">' . $phtml . '</div></div>';
```

Comment: `div is generated dynamically` So call method once element added to the DOM

Answer (score 0):

Use "text-align: justify;" property. and give width of the Div in % or in em not in pixels.

Comment: Div need to have a fix width.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#mainproductafilioright').delegate('.product', 'change', function(){
    // apply your script here
});
```

And maybe on resize event apply it too.

Comment: `// apply your script here` You mean the jquery? I applied it and it didn't work.

Comment: "I found a script here on stack overflow that is supposed to stretch a text to a div width" 
That script.